# How can I get all HTML With attributes Form String

Tags: javascript

I need to get Html tags with attributes extract from string

```
    var text = '<span class="basic-c-style-22-p16">P</span><a href="#">link
<span class="basic-c-style-21-p16">Some Text </span></a>'
```

I need to get outPut

```
  var openHtmlTag = [
    <span class="basic-c-style-22-p16">, <a href="#">, <span class="basic-c-style-21-p16">
  ]

  var CloseHtmlTag = [
    </span>,</a>,</span>
   ]
```

Thanks
vinothkumar

Comment: Your string will produce **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** error

Comment: Now i am fixed the problem Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: What's the need for this? Would it not be better to work with the elements whole rather than splitting the tags?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? If you want to fill something inside the a tag (a text for example) you could just set the value of this text into your string.

Comment: is it not possible to get it. can you please help to me..